# are static_cast<double> and double the same?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion, static-cast

I am a beginner in C++ casting.
I need to know are `static_cast<double>` and `double` ex-changable in any code?

In the following code can I replace `static_cast<double>` with `double`? which is much shorter. Do I loose any readability?

```
a= static_cast<double> ( 3 ) / static_cast<double>( 7 );
```

How about `static_cast` of other basic types such as `int`, `char`, `size_t`?

According to explanations they must be the same. But is there any exceptional case?

Comment: You can replace them with `(double)` if you really want to.

Comment: If you don't use `static_cast`, you can and should use `double(...)` instead of `(double)...`, eg: `double(3)`, `double(somevar)`, etc.

Comment: You can also use literals: `a = 3.0 / 7.0`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what is the difference between `double(...)` and `(double)...`?

Comment: One question with incompatible solutions suggested by experts, how does somebody link this question to somewhere else and feels that the answer is clear??

Comment: The difference is that `double foo() / bar())`  clearly does the cast on the whole expression, whereas `(double) foo()/bar()` is visually ambiguous. (And in fact casts the result of `foo` before the division; the whitespace in the example is intentionally misleading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

---

The C++11 draft standard calls `T(number)` functional notation and `(T) number` cast notation. Given that the expression list is a single expression, they're equivalent:

> §5.2.3/1 A *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-specifier*
>   (14.6) followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value
>   of the specified type given the expression list. If the expression
>   list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is
>   equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the
>   corresponding cast expression (5.4). [...]

`(T) number` can call `static_cast`, which has the following behavior in this situation:

> §5.2.9/4 Otherwise, an expression e can be explicitly converted to a
>   type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the
>   declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary
>   variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an explicit conversion is the
>   same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using
>   the temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The expression
>   `e` is used as a glvalue if and only if the initialization uses it as
>   a glvalue.

You could save yourself a lot of typing and just use floating literals (which has type double).

```
a = 3.0 / 7.0;
```

Comment: what does it mean by `Given that the operand is a single expression`?

Comment: @ziftron `T(x1)` instead of `T(x1, x2, ...)`